# Are ES6 class methods writable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I feel like I remember seeing something on es-discuss saying that es6 class methods won't be writable, as in

```
class Foo{
    method(){}
}
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Foo.prototype, "method").writable -> false
```

I tried it in Microsoft Edge and traceur and they're both writable, I can't for the life of me figure out how to find it in the spec either.

So are they writable? or has the class spec just not fully caught on yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are writable.

According to [14.5.14 Runtime Semantics: ClassDefinitionEvaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation),

> 19. If *ClassBody*<sub>opt</sub> is not present, let *methods* be a new empty [List](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-list-and-record-specification-type).
> 20. Else, let *methods* be NonConstructorMethodDefinitions of *ClassBody*.
> 21. For each *ClassElement* *m* in order from *methods*
>
>     1. If IsStatic of *m* is **false**, then
>
>        1. Let *status* be the result of performing PropertyDefinitionEvaluation for *m* with arguments *proto* and **false**.
>     2. Else,
>
>        1. Let *status* be the result of performing PropertyDefinitionEvaluation for *m* with arguments *F* and **false**.

And PropertyDefinitionEvaluation is defined in [14.3.9 Runtime Semantics: PropertyDefinitionEvaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation):

> *MethodDefinition* : *PropertyName* `(` *StrictFormalParameters* `)` `{`
>   *FunctionBody* `}`
>
> 1. Let *methodDef* be DefineMethod of *MethodDefinition* with argument *object*.
> 2. [ReturnIfAbrupt](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-returnifabrupt)(*methodDef*).
> 3. Perform [SetFunctionName](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-setfunctionname)(*methodDef*.[[closure]], *methodDef*.[[key]]).
> 4. Let *desc* be the [Property Descriptor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-property-descriptor-specification-type){[[Value]]: *methodDef*.[[closure]], [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: *enumerable*,
>      [[Configurable]]: **true**}.
> 5. Return [DefinePropertyOrThrow](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-definepropertyorthrow)(*object*, *methodDef*.[[key]], *desc*).

To sum up, they are configurable, writable and non-enumerable.